# Apache mod_proxy or or passthrough?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my Apache server I have 2 separate vhosts: foo.example.com & bar.example.com

I need requests passed to foo.example.com/bar/uri to be passed to bar.example.com/uri transparently to the user (for the sake of SSL).  It is hosted on the same apache instance but as I said, under a different vhost.

I've tried various combinations of RewriteRule with [PT] but I keep getting an invalid URI.  A regular rewrite will not work by itself because it needs to back through the URL engine to be picked up by the other vhost.

An example I've tried (in foo obviously):

```
RewriteRule ^/bar/([^/\.]+)/?$ http://bar.example.com/$1 [PT]
```

Is this the correct approach or should I be using ProxyPass(Reverse) back to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?bar/([^/.]+)/?$ http://bar.example.com/$1 [L,P]
```